# Katalon error - invalid session id: No active session with ID

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, saucelabs, katalon

We encountered this error in the middle of a test run and after that execution just stucks on a web page and then it starts looking for an eleemnt which is not there on the webpage and this runs for indefinite time with this error

```
invalid session id: No active session with ID 335a88cad75f69d202c75f31acb20aee5dc88cd1
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at ProfilePage.clickProfileIcon (/Users/............./page-objects/profile.js:30:22)
    at World.<anonymous> (/Users/runner....../tests/step-definitions/profiles.steps.js:115:3)
```

This is randomly ha[ppening on whn running on Katalon studio I check on Katalon studio  community forum but not found any thing.

Also this is happening when running on remote testing service prociders like saucelabs and Lambda test.

Comment: Any update here, Katalon support team?